# JBoss migration tool for JBoss AS 4.2.3 to WildFLy 14

Tags: server, jboss

Does JBoss migration tool support migration from JBoss AS 4.2.3 to WildFly 14?

Comment: From both [this outdated guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/CMTOOL/JBoss+Server+Migration+Tool+User+Guide#JBossServerMigrationToolUserGuide-SupportedServerMigrations) and [the list of source versions](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-server-migration/tree/master/migrations/wildfly14.0) on the up-to-date github it seems that the lowest supported source version is wildfly 8.

Comment: Thank you Aaron :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your migration !